# jquery single click doesn't work on mousedown/hover event

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/vd6vG/

If you mousedown over the td's they turn red, but if you click nothing happens

So I assume from this that a click event doesn't fire a mousedown? How can I get it to also work on click?

Note: I'm actually doing this with SVG but this table version shows the same problem

Here's the jquery for the benefit of SO rules

```
var md = false;

$(document).mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        md = true;

        }).mouseup(function(){

        md = false;

       })

$("td").hover(function(){

    if(md) $(this).css("background","#f00");

})
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen here? You mousedown, set `md` to true, then when you release the mouse, its back to false, exactly what you want? I added log statements: http://jsfiddle.net/vd6vG/1/ -- Click and drag on some `td`, it works fine.

Comment: single click doesn't work, as per the title

Comment: Well there's no click handler.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put in a separate handler for the click event.

```
$("td").click(function(){

    $(this).css("background","#f00");

})
```

Comment: is this the only solution? I can't get the object from the SVG, my fault I should have posted the SVG version

Comment: @jimsmith: You can edit your question and add the SVG example.

Comment: @jimsmith I remember correctly. I have an SVG-based project at work where I attach click events to SVG `<circle>` objects. In my case, I believe I've used `$('#svg').on('click', 'circle', function() { /* do stuff */ });` Similar principles should apply to other SVG elements.

Comment: J. David Smith -  IT WORKS Thank you very much!